# Set up auto-mounting virtual CD drives on Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, compact-disc, virtual-drive

How can I set up Windows 7 to auto-mount CD images as needed?

I have a bunch of old games on CD (eg. Starcraft Broodwar) that I have ripped to ISO or IMG/CDD files.  Until recently, I used Daemon Tools (on Windows XP) to mount them but found it a real hassle since I had to manually mount each disk each time I wanted to play.

I just moved to a laptop with Windows 7 and **I want to set things up so that when I attempt to run any particular game, the appropriate CD will auto-mount and I can play without having to do anything manually.** Assume that these are all games that would work if I put the physical CD in the drive.

Has anyone done this?  If so, would you please discuss in detail how you did? (Some kind of scripting solution would be perfectly ok.)

The laptop in question runs Windows 7 Home Premium (version 6.1 build 7600). I consider myself a power user of Windows XP but am still finding my way around Windows 7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using virtual Clone drive you can mount and unmount images form the command line using 
daemon -unmount {drive#}
and
daemon -mount {drive#}, imagelocation

This should be easily added to a .bat or scripted file before launching the program.

Answer (score 0):

I recall with the older 3.x version of DT there was a helper application someone had written that would let you set up shortcuts which would mount an image and then launch another program. I would imagine something similar exists for version 4.x but my ability to search for one here at work is limited (web filtering).